# Using JasperReport API

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I got stuck with one problem since a few months ago. Now I recall it and stand still get the same problem. I want to make JasperReports Server can print report without exporting to pdf format. And I also got some clues for that. To do so, we need to use JasperReport API. However, I don't really know how to use that library. Also as I searched, I can see only this link: http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/jasperreports-library-tutorial but it's not describable.

- Is it the right API?
- If it is my right, have you ever experienced with printer as mention above?
- Do you have sample process, sample code, or configuration?

*Please help me solve. Any ideas, or solutions are really appreciated*

Sakura

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/printservice/index.html. 
Note the name of the printers are commented. You will need to change the name to suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you. I want to see it